# Disrupror consumer resubmiting data

Tags: java, message-passing, disruptor-pattern

I want to use LMAX's disruptor but i'm not sure that my use case is fit for it. Basically there is one or 2 producers and n consumers. The trick is that when a consumer receives an event and checks some data on it it has to republish the data if it can't consume it right away (it's basically a polling scheme) . I create the ring buffer with a capacity i'm not worried is too small but now my question is :  is it safe to request new sequences and publish from an event handler or can this somehow break the functionality? From a small test i made this seems safe enough but i don't know how it will behave in my particular case. I'm worried that the onEvent method might be called after i request a sequence but before i update-> publish the new object and i really don't know how the disruptor treats these cases

Comment: I would expect you can't consume a message until it has been published. And you can't re-use a message until it has been consumed.  A key assumption of the disruptor is the producer and consumer are non-blocking.

Comment: so basically if i get a sequence in consumer A and then a sequence in consumer B but i publish the B sequence before the A sequence then that will be visible first even if the sequence number (long) is higher, and subsequent calls to next() on the ring buffer will eventually return the A sequence ?

Comment: Events are only marked as visible to subscribers once all the preceding events are published. i.e slot 15 is only marked as visible once 14 is marked as published.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (without having the `EventHandler` re-publish the events) would be to implement a separate "republish" `Disruptor`. If a consumer thread finds that it can't consume an event right away, it writes the event to that buffer, and separate threads would then pass those messages back into the main event queue.

This will increase the number of writers to the main queue, but that seems unavoidable given the use case. One other potential problem with this solution is that republished events will have to be consumed *after* any new messages which were added to the main queue before republishing.